# Batch File To Delete Folders Only

Tags: internet-explorer, batch-file

I'm trying to find a way with a batch file that will delete specific contents of a folder. The folder is the temporary internet files folder, 'Content.IE5'

The problem is that I need to leave the 2 files in that folder called: 'desktop.ini' and 'index.dat', but delete the folders that are created in there by Internet Explorer - they have changing names of the folders too.

Does anyone know how this could be achieved?
Thanks.

Comment: What are you using?  If I was trying what you're doing, I'd use AutoHotKey to backup desktop.ini and index.dat, then delete everything, then restore the two files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered calling

```
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 8
```

This seems to be one way to clean up the Temporary Internet Files from the command line, and it can also do [several other things](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/clear-ie7-browsing-history-from-the-command-line/).  Running the [Disk Cleanup Tool](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315246) is also an option.  You can create a group of things that you want to clean up with `cleanmgr /sageset:[n]`, and then call `cleanmgr /sagerun:[n]`.

These aren't as fun as writing your own batch file to delete them, but they will probably accomplish your goal with less work.

Comment: +1. Not only will they accomplish the goal with less work, but they will do it more correctly, because `index.dat` will be cleaned up as well.

Answer (score 2):

Well, one must assume that you are talking about the index and desktop. ini in the root of that folder. I also believe that those are the only files in that folder (but that could be just because I dont use IE.)

The easiest script I can think of for this would be the following (of course you can always alter the path to the user environment variable if this is more than just for yourself).;

```
cd "C:\Users\uname\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5"
for /D %%a in (*.) do rd /Q /S %%a
```

This should loop through each directory in the Content.IE5 folder and recursively delete that folder. You should be aware that it cannot delete currently opened files. It will also leave the two files you mentioned intact.

I hope that this answers your question

Comment: Use `in (*)`. Otherwise directories with a dot in the name are not included!